# C: String search in txt file and output

Tags: c, string, search

For my university project, I have to write a C program called "jukebox" that lets the user put in a file name, a search string, and then displays every line of the text file containing that search string.

Every line (98 in total) contains "*artist name - song name*". The output shall be "*track number - artist name - song name*"

I have already searched and found some snippets of information but I cannot seem to make sense out of it and it seems as if I do not understand C well enough to apply that to my problem, therefore this is my last hope to find help.

I would like to know: what have I done wrong, how exactly to use *strstr* and *getline* and what to put in it, and how to printf the found information correctly.
Another problem I encounter is missing every first letter when printing the whole text file (accidentally).

My code so far is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char fileName[60]; // per definition Jukebox.txt
char searchString[60];
char textinfo[60]; // contains artist and song name

// maximum of letters per line is 60

int temp;
int i = 1;
int x = 0;
size_t result = 100;

FILE *pFile;

int main(void) {

    printf("Please enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s", fileName);


    pFile = fopen("Jukebox.txt", "r");


    if (pFile == NULL) {
        printf("File could not be opened!\n");
    }
    else {

        printf("Please enter search string: ");
        scanf("%s", searchString);


        textinfo = strstr(  );


        printf("%s\n", textinfo);

        for(i = 0; x < 1; i++) {

            char *p = textinfo;

            getline(&p, &list, pFile);

            printf("%d: %s", i , textinfo);


            if((temp = fgetc(pFile)) == EOF) {
                x = 2;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Yep, you are confused -- but at least you are thinking along the right lines. Unless you can guarantee each line is 59 characters are less, increase you array sizes. What you want to do is keep a counter, `size_t trackno = 0;`. Then you want to loop with `while (fgets (buffer, max_size, FILE*)) { char *found = strstr (buffer, searchString); if (found) { trackno += 1; /* split line into artist name, artist song, output track, name, song */ }` If you edit and show 10 or so of your lines of input -- then we can help further.

Comment: Firstly, thank you for the response. I am a bit confused on where to put the loop - I thought to put it to replace the for loop, am I right?

Comment: Where is `list` defined? Use a field width in `scanf` to avoid potential buffer overflows, e.g. `scanf("%59s", result)`. Lastly, `strstr` returns NULL if it doesn't find the substring. Check its return value.

Comment: That was my fault, I meant to remove that - sorry

Comment: No worries. You are reading data line-by-line from a file. So your read-loop is `while (fgtes (buffer, max_size, fp)) { /* do your stuff on each line here */ }`. When you run out of lines to read, the read-loop automatically exits. You always control your read-loop with the return of the input function being used... Edit and post example input and I can show you how to do what you are needing to do, but I can't just guess at what your input looks like. Just post the first 10 lines with `\`\`\`` (3-backticks) before the first and after the last line so it formats as fixed-text.

Comment: So my input looks like ```No Angels – Daylight In Your Eyes 
Travis – Sing 
Sofaplanet – Liebficken 
Buddy vs. DJ The Wave – Ab in den Süden 
Enya – Only Time 
Vengaboys – Uncle John From Jamaica 
The Corrs – Breathless 
Eminem feat. Dido – Stan 
Anastacia – I’m Outta Love 
Dido – Life For Rent```